# Handle MaterializeCSS dismissable collection event in JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I want to know how I can handle the "dismissable" class as event of a MaterializeCSS collection in JQuery or JavaScript. 
Is there any ability like ondismiss="" in HTML?

The dismissable is only enabled on mobile devices and represents the swipe-off gesture.

[Materialize Collections Documentation](http://materializecss.com/collections.html)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to add a hook for when the action is triggered, or do you want to trigger it manually?

Comment: I want to add a hook for it, that I can handle it when the user swipes the collection item away.

Answer (score 1):

It uses [hammerjs](http://hammerjs.github.io/) to handle the swipe events so currently there is no way to handle an on dismiss event. If you want to edit the source code, you can edit the `transitions.js` file on line `114`:

```
$this.velocity({ height: 0, padding: 0,
  }, {duration: 200, queue: false, easing: 'easeOutQuad', complete:
  function() { $this.remove(); }
});
```

This is where it handles the callback of the animation and actually removes the collection element. You can add a [jQuery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to define your own custom event to handle.

If you do edit the source code, just remember you need to recompile the javascript into the materialize.js file.

If you are interested in something like incorporated into the project, you can submit an issue at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize).